Jumping between the category of sheaves, coherent sheaves and the derived category
Let $X$ be say a locally ringed space. I'm trying to find some "motivational" ways to describe why someone would ever be interested in the categories $\textbf{Sh}(X), \textbf{Coh}(X)$ and $D^b(\textbf{Coh}(X))$.
To convince someone that $\textbf{Sh}(X)$ is something they should consider, I think its fine to argue that since $\textbf{Top}(X)$ is somewhat ill-behaved not being even abelian, its worth considering $\textbf{Sh}(X)$.
To go from $\textbf{Sh}(X)$ to $\textbf{Coh}(X)$ I'm not so sure anymore. I guess a good reason would be that the coherent sheaves behave more similarly to vector bundles rather than arbitary sheaves? Also there apparently is some trouble with $\textbf{Sh}(X)$ behaving nicely with pullbacks and tensor products in some instances, does $\textbf{Coh}(X)$ resolve this?
Explaining to someone why they would want to jump from $\textbf{Coh}(X)$ to $D^b(\textbf{Coh}(X))$, I have very little to say about.
Anyone more experienced here care to give some hand-wavy description of this?

The kernel / cokernel of a morphism of locally free sheaves might not be locally free anymore, hence the jump from vector bundles to coherent sheaves. To do cohomology is one of the reasons to jump from coherent sheaves to its derived category.

I think in the wild, $X$ usually has a little more structure which makes coherence natural to consider. (Say, $X$ is a locally noetherian scheme, for example.)

The category $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$ generalizes the notion of open subspaces of $U$ (together with suitable descent properties). The category $\mathbf{Coh}(X)$ generalizes the notion of modules with a suitable finiteness conditions. The category $D^b(\mathbf{Coh}(X))$ is a suitable passage to homological algebra.

All these categories provide a context for usual operations such as cohomology, but I will try to explain why they are interesting on there own.
Indeed there are interesting properties of categories we should look for, so there is two categories we can add to your list.
1) QCoh($X$).
It is also abelian but with infinite sums, so we have all kind of colimits. It is AB3 in the sense of Grothendieck (and even AB5).
2)$D^{\text{perf}}(X)$.
It is the sub category in $D^b($Coh$(X))$ generated by locally free sheaves. In this category you can derive the tensor product functor $\otimes$, so you have a monoidal category. Notice that for a smooth scheme $D^{\text{perf}}(X)=D^b($Coh$(X))$, so you can forget this definition if you just look at smooth schemes.
As you also mentioned, you want some functors between this categories. I already considered $\otimes$, but obviously there is also $f^*$ and $f_*$. However in each situations it is not so clear that $f_*$ and $f^*$ preserve (quasi-)coherents sheaves. For your last category, you need that $R^if_*$ preserves coherence and is $0$ for $i>>0$. So you need hypothesis to ensure all of this. For these questions, theorems are usuals and I will restrict my attention to schemes. For instance you have :
Theorem (example) If $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism between noetherian schemes, then $f^*$ preserves coherence.
For $R^i f_*$ you need a proper assumption on $f$, so you may assume that $X$ and $Y$ are projective varieties.
So you should restrict to smooth projective varieties if you want to have good properties for these categories.
Now we must wonder why we want to study these categories for themselves. Obviously it is intersting to compute the order of a sheaf, or its cohomology, but what about the structure of the category ? We have two famous results:
Theorem (Gabriel) If $X$ and $Y$ are projective varieties such that Coh$(X)\simeq$ Coh$(Y)$, then $X\simeq Y$ as a ringed space.
References : Des catégories abéliennes (chapter $6$) is the original paper, Gabriel proved the result for the category QCoh$(X)$ with the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are noetherian schemes. In Rosenberg's reconstruction theorem you can find a reference for the quasi-separated case. Finally in Gabriel's theorem and birational geometry you can find the coherent case and a relation with a well-known result in algebraic geometry.
So Coh$(X)$ is a complete invariant for the classification of shemes. It seems interesting, but as you may know, classification of schemes is almost impossible, so this result asserts that this invariant is really hard to use, and impossible to compare with others. For the derived category we have the same result.
Theorem (Thomason, Balmer) If $X$ and $Y$ are projective varieties such that $D^b($Coh$(X))\simeq D^b($Coh$(Y))$ with there monoidal structure, then $X\simeq Y$ as a ringed space.
Reference : Presheaves of triangulated categories and reconstruction of schemes.
We make the same conclusion : this invariant is not so usefull. Previous theorems rely on a Spec construction for abelian categories/ monoidal categories.
Last but not least is $D^b(X)$ without the monoidal structure. It is a very important object in derived geometry (I still assume that my varieties are smooth projective schemes). In a special case it is a complete invariant.
Therem (Bondal, Orlov) If $\omega_X$ is ample or anti-ample, then $D^b(X)$ is a complete invariant.
But it is not the case for general varieties.
Definition : $X$ and $Y$ are calle Mukai partners if $D^b(X)\simeq D^b(Y)$.
Now $X$ and $Y$ can be Mukai partners without being isomorphics ! It is similar to the homotopy relation : it is not an isomorphism but it can allows to pass from a variety to another with a lot of common invariants but which is easier to handle.
So finally which invariants of $X$ can be found in $D^b(X)$? It is a large question so here is a non exhaustive list :

the dimension.
the kodaira dimension.
the order of the canonical sheaf.
the Hochschild ring.

An intersting textbook to introduce this subject is Huybrechts' one Fourier-Mukai Transforms in Algebraic Geometry.
